# Snowflake Retrieve value from Semi Structured Data

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to retrieve the health value from Snowflake semi structured data in a **variant** column called **extra** from table **X**.

An example of the code can be seen below:

```
[
  {
    "party":
 "[{\"class\":\"Farmer\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"ethnicity\":\"NativeAmerican\",\"health\":2},
{\"class\":\"Adventurer\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"ethnicity\":\"White\",\"health\":3},
{\"class\":\"Farmer\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"ethnicity\":\"White\",\"health\":0},
{\"class\":\"Banker\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"ethnicity\":\"White\",\"health\":0}
  }
]
```

I have tried reading the Snowflake documentation from https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/querying-semi-structured-data

I have also tried the following queries to flatten the query:

```
SELECT result.value:health AS PartyHealth 
FROM X 
WHERE value = 'Trail'
AND name = 'Completed' 
AND PartyHealth > 0, 
TABLE(FLATTEN(X, 'party')) result
```

AND

```
SELECT [0]['party'][0]['health'] AS Health
FROM X 
WHERE value = 'Trail'
AND name = 'Completed' 
AND PH > 0;
```

I am trying to retrieve the health value from table **X** from column **extra** which contains the the variant party, which has 4 repeating values [0-3]. Im not sure how to do this is someone able to tell me how to query semi structured data in Snowflake, considering the documentation doesn't make much sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the JSON value you posted seems wrong formatted (might be a copy paste issue).

Here's an example that works:

- first your JSON formatted:

  `[{ "party": [ {"class":"Farmer","gender":"Female","ethnicity":"NativeAmerican","health":2}, {"class":"Adventurer","gender":"Male","ethnicity":"White","health":3}, {"class":"Farmer","gender":"Male","ethnicity":"White","health":0}, {"class":"Banker","gender":"Female","ethnicity":"White","health":0} ] }]`
- create a table to test:

  `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE myvariant (v variant);`
- insert the JSON value into this table:

  `INSERT INTO myvariant SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{ "party": [ {"class":"Farmer","gender":"Female","ethnicity":"NativeAmerican","health":2}, {"class":"Adventurer","gender":"Male","ethnicity":"White","health":3}, {"class":"Farmer","gender":"Male","ethnicity":"White","health":0}, {"class":"Banker","gender":"Female","ethnicity":"White","health":0} ] }]');`
- now, to select a value you start from **column name**, in my case **v**, and as your JSON is an array inside, I specify first value **[0]**, and from there expand, so something like this:

  `SELECT v[0]:party[0].health FROM myvariant;`

Above gives me:

[image]

For the other rows you can simply do:

```
SELECT v[0]:party[1].health FROM myvariant;
SELECT v[0]:party[2].health FROM myvariant;
SELECT v[0]:party[3].health FROM myvariant;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to make the data more like a table ... I find it easier to work with than the JSON :-)

Code at bottom - just copy/paste and it runs in Snowflake returning screenshot below.

[Key Doco is Lateral Flatten](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html)

[image]

```
 SELECT  d4.path, d4.value 
 from  
 lateral flatten(input=>PARSE_JSON('[{ "party": [ {"class":"Farmer","gender":"Female","ethnicity":"NativeAmerican","health":2}, {"class":"Adventurer","gender":"Male","ethnicity":"White","health":3}, {"class":"Farmer","gender":"Male","ethnicity":"White","health":0}, {"class":"Banker","gender":"Female","ethnicity":"White","health":0} ] }]') ) as d  ,  
 lateral flatten(input=> value) as d2 ,  
 lateral flatten(input=> d2.value) as d3 ,  
 lateral flatten(input=> d3.value) as d4
```